# Keep getting error for localList

Tags: java, android, eclipse

OK i cant seem to get this error to go away on localList.  The error reads localList cannot be resolved to a variable.  I tried to put a variable but it just gave me more errors. I even tried to delete the localList but it doesnt seem to resolve the problem.

Heres the code

```
  private class CustomAdapter
    extends ArrayAdapter<ListRapBeats.RowData>
  {
    public CustomAdapter(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, List<ListRapBeats.RowData> paramList)
    {
      super(paramInt2, paramList, localList);

    }

    public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup)
    {
      ListRapBeats.RowData localRowData = (ListRapBeats.RowData)getItem(paramInt);
      if (paramView == null)
      {
        paramView = ListRapBeats.this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        paramView.setTag(new ViewHolder(paramView));
      }
      ViewHolder localViewHolder = (ViewHolder)paramView.getTag();
      localViewHolder.gettitle().setText(localRowData.mTitle);
      ImageView localImageView = localViewHolder.getImage();
      if ((ListRapBeats.this.TestSongExists(localRowData.mfileName)) || (ListRapBeats.this.downloadedSongs.contains(localRowData.mfileName)))
      {
        localImageView.setImageResource(ListRapBeats.this.imgid[0].intValue());
        return paramView;
      }
      if ((localRowData.mfileName.equals("one")) || (localRowData.mfileName.equals("two")) || (localRowData.mfileName.equals("three")))
      {
        localImageView.setImageResource(ListRapBeats.this.imgid[0].intValue());
        return paramView;
      }
    return localImageView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
      private ImageView i11 = null;
      private View mRow;
      private TextView title = null;

      public ViewHolder(View paramView)
      {
        this.mRow = paramView;
      }

      public ImageView getImage()
      {
        if (this.i11 == null) {
          this.i11 = ((ImageView)this.mRow.findViewById(R.id.itemlogo));
        }
        return this.i11;
      }

      public TextView gettitle()
      {
        if (this.title == null) {
          this.title = ((TextView)this.mRow.findViewById(R.id.title));
        }
        return this.title;
      }
    }
  }

  private class RowData
  {
    protected int mId;
    protected String mTitle;
    protected String mfileName;

    RowData(int paramInt, String paramString1, String paramString2)
    {
      this.mId = paramInt;
      this.mTitle = paramString1;
      this.mfileName = paramString2;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
      return this.mId + " " + this.mTitle + " " + this.mfileName;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See your code here:

```
public CustomAdapter(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, List<ListRapBeats.RowData> paramList)
```

==> your list is called `paramList` not `localList`. There is no variable with the name `localList` declared in your code that is why you get *localList cannot be resolved to a variable* error.

---

**Update:** the code where you call the super-constructor doesn't make sense to me:

```
super(paramInt2, paramList, localList);
```

==> There is no constructor for [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) that would take an int + 2 lists (I guess you did not want localList to be an int..) as the parameters. That is why the error: *ArrayAdapter(int, List, int) is undefined on the super(paramInt2, paramList, localList);* shows up. What is the idea behind this code?

Comment: when i add int localList in the CustomAdapter i get this error The constructor ArrayAdapter<ListRapBeats.RowData>(int, List<ListRapBeats.RowData>, int) is undefined on the super(paramInt2, paramList, localList);